# how to redirect on a if loop html

Tags: javascript, html, redirect

I'm a kind of noob in HTML
here's my code 
the problem:
the if loop needs to redirect to a HTML containing links to all the levels
`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>title game beta</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    //crap ton of functions
    // basicly theres a function thats updates the frames 
    // theres a if ststement and that if statement
    // needs to redirect like this:
    function update()
    {
      if (score = 6)
      {
        //redirect
      }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: an if statement is not a loop. also it'd be good if you explain your problem more in deep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

// Sets the new href (URL) for the current window.

```
window.location.href = "https://www.example.com";
```